# ActiveAdmin attributes table row: display an associated object without a link to it's show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a custom ActiveAdmin page with a `show` action that displays a bunch of attributes. I added a row to display an associated object, but don't want it to link to that object's show page. How can I suppress the link? Example below:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Thingy do
  show do |thingy|
    attributes_table do
      row :name
      row :date
      row :associate do
        thingy.associate
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The `name` and `date` rows display like 'Label: Value'. The `associate` rows does also, but 'Value' is a link to the show page for that particular associate object, which I don't want.

Comment: What if you try `row(:associate) { thingy.associate.name }`?

Comment: @JoshKovach either you're a genius or I'm an idiot. Either way, it worked